# Lumen + Doctrine findAll returns array of empty objects

Tags: serialization, doctrine, lumen

I've setup Lumen with Doctrine (laravel-doctrine/orm)

When I try to fetch results (ie $this->em->getRepository(Student::class)->findAll();) on an HTTP Route, I get an array of empty curly brackets.

How can I make serialization run correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to wrap your result with `Illuminate\Support\Collection` class, something like:

```
use  Illuminate\Support\Collection;

return Collection::make(
    $this->em->getRepository(Student::class)->findAll()
);
```

After that, modify your `Student` class by assigning it to `Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable` contract.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;

class Student implements Arrayable
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Next, you should implement `toArray` method to your `Student` class:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;

class Student implements Arrayable
{
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getId(),
            // ... and so on ...
        ];
    }
}
```